# One hypothesis concerning Hamming distance matrix

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, coding-theory

Suppose $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_m$ are different strings of the same length n.

And let $V = [v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n]$ be a matrix such that $V_{i, j}$ is a Hamming distance between $a_i$ and $a_j$.

Hypothesis is that $v_1$ can't be equal to $\alpha_2 v_2 + \ldots + \alpha_n v_n$, where $\alpha_2 + \ldots + \alpha_m = 1$.

If this hypothesis is correct or even incorrect one more complex problem will be solved.

Do you have any ideas about it?

Comment: Not sure whether it is relevant - just asking. Are we talking about strings of bits (0/1), or can we have a larger alphabet?

Comment: Alphabet is larger.

Answer (score 1):

It's getting late here, so I may have missed something. But I think the following example answers the question in the negative.

Let the alphabet be $\{a,b\}$ and consider the set of all strings of length $2$: $a_1=aa$, $a_2=ab$, $a_3=ba$, $a_4=bb$. Then we get
$$
V=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0&1&1&2\\
1&0&2&1\\
1&2&0&1\\
2&1&1&0\end{array}\right).
$$
Here we have the linear dependency relation among the columns
$$
v_1=v_2+v_3-v_4,
$$
which is of the undesired type.

Comment: This is the smallest counterexample in the sense that it is easy to see that the matrix $V$ always has full rank, if there are only three strings.